# Error installing apk programmatically: "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class"

Tags: android

I am trying the following code to install apk file saved on the SD Card and getting following exception: "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity}". In the code, `file` is representing the apk file's SD Card path.

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
resultIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
resultIntent.setClassName("com.android.packageinstaller", ".PackageInstallerActivity");
 startActivity(resultIntent);
```

How do I manage this?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to read [this blog post](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=98) on how to install and remove packages using the PackageInstaller.

Note that since the package installer is registered to handle the MIME type `application/vnd.android.package-archive`, you shouldn't have to specify the intent class name explicitly; the intent resolver should find the right one to start.

Also, the operation will succeed only if the user has enabled `INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS`. This is directly related to the failure you are seeing, but it's something to keep in mind as you'll likely run into that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` like so:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
resultIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

And then call

```
startActivity(resultIntent);
```

NOTE! that the condition regarding `INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS`, as mentioned earlier by Franci Penov, still must be valid!

Comment: After a quick recap on my old code I noticed that I create the Intent with an empty constructor and manually set the Action afterwards. This is now reflected in my modified answer. I don't know, however, if this makes any difference whatsoever. I tried my code again and it works. I don't know if there are any "special circumstances" that make my solution work or you guy's brave attempts to fail.

Comment: Hi dbm,

I am facing the simmiler problem and tried out your solution but still getting this error "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.android.packageinstaller/.PackageInstallerActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

What kind of permission required in Manifest file???

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for bringing my attention to the activity part of my above example! I haven't defined the Activity in my AndroidManifest.xml file since I don't have such an activity there. Neither have I called the `setClassName` function on the Intent as I wrongfully wrote in my original answer. Try to remove the `resultIntent.setClassName(...)` line and hopefully it will work then :-)